# How do I correct slow video fps in xscreensaver?

Tags: xscreensaver

I recently updated my Ubuntu 14.04 and installed xscreensaver. It all runs but the screen savers are slow and choppy when they run. I increased the fps to max and increased image/video play speed but it's still half speed of the preview. How can I correct this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't, install the package "linux-image-extra-(yourversionhere)" -- hopefully it has your graphics drivers in it, if not, you might need to get them from somewhere else.  Very important.

Comment: I had not considered that course of action. For whatever reason an AMD Palm graphics driver was installed instead of an AMD HD Radeon graphics driver. After installing the right driver package my fps run at proper speed.